# updating a column with array type using other columns in postgresql

Tags: arrays, postgresql

I have a table like this:

```
+-----+------------+-------+--------+-----------+
| ID  |  val1      | val2  | val3   |  array_3  |
+-----+------------+-------+--------+-----------+
| 100 |  110       | 25    | 53     |{110,25,53}|
| 101 |  56        | 75    | 59     |{56,75,59} |
| 102 |  65        | 93    | 82     |{65,93,82} |
| 103 |  75        | 70    | 80     |{75,70,80} |
+-----+------------+-------+--------+-----------+
```

imagine I have the values for *ID, val1, val2 and val3* columns and I want the resulting array in the **array_3** table which is an array type and its size is 1*3. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Array constructor?

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/c297a/

```
SELECT "ID", ARRAY[val1,val2,val3], array_3
FROM table1;
```

To put the output in a separate table use `CREATE TABLE .. AS`.

Comment: thank you, already informative. but my array_3 column is empty now and I want to fill it with the values like that I've already out in the table.

Comment: @f.ashouri Then use the array constructor in an `UPDATE`. It was hard to tell exactly what you were wanting to do with it.

Answer (score 2):

`update mytable 
set array_3=ARRAY[pix_val1, pix_val2]`